# Adding tags retrospectively and git log

Tags: git, git-log, git-tag

I'd like to be able to query git and output a list of changes between tagged releases to create simple release notes.

I've retrospectively added tags to commits in my git repo and pushed these to origin as well. But now when I try and list the commits between tags, the result are not right.

Here's my log:

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline --decorate
8f326b8ac5dc4ae5d1e9097d91ef460a39e9bda2 (HEAD, tag: 1.1.65, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) following fixes done
aef34c6dec4890384ca5fd318988d14a5b7af327 chat Input Field to have padding from the left....
adbad9b9aa74bb9664521780adb50272181eca23 changed setting name from LogEntries to Live Log
58476d5f72abe603c2b0ec3bf54a40a82fbafb90 Merge branch 'master' of ssh://github.com/fezzee/FezzeeIOS
77f3d951a3ad7099667b98dd1622279da5fc8c3d prevent legacy setting lock in, remove 2 observers when view is unloaded, possible better test in 
ed48862949890604b044e4cf20bc6bcff4a8674a Merge branch 'master' of ssh://github.com/fezzee/FezzeeIOS
07bf561ef4eb55fddd732d796a0014aa8d992df8 (tag: 1.1.64) Fixed Issues:
e3119c296b4b2df91eec035cbd05f256f86a2150 Put username (friendly name) UNDER Avatar in scrolling area, rather than next to it
25cb2fcf57915b417d9f8404f1eca9c44704245d Merge branch 'master' of ssh://github.com/fezzee/FezzeeIOS
5bd194a9ade3cfc172e218c43b398ebe9bce7126 version v1.1.62
2910fd959e7273943461986328b60b4b40b5e08c (tag: 1.1.63) following issues are completed
4893a19ad4cc2c9e4a4a89ec561a194506349974 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/fezzee/FezzeeIOS
43dda4ed132e6f748e02f6a2ad3ff1b1d4870566 Following Issues Fixed:-
ac8e14dc810c85ddab09e25a3efdc3c7b1cc8ff5 fixed merge conflict
090c3f3d99df70df25e5d54d96192b58e805a619 (tag: 1.1.62) Pull letest
0d2b5bc1e247ea4f9eef247fb6e24d4bf1e48948 Inform user about phone number on which activation code has been sent
8d1e4688149accc8d183bb74c6a21f61f37f3497 Artist image is not updated in app, when changes to the image have been made in JSON and downloade
61b90f31254a3bdcc7508b6bcfe73d02d181f3eb some Ui changes On boarding And pull latest update
c90c963592cd3fe9f86333df991083d7ab444ebb (tag: 1.1.60/61) Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/fezzee/FezzeeIOS
f63df18631f9020f8775ed9259d99e84fb46cccb add booked acts on an  "undefined stage"  but have them displayed in the artists list
418ff451d236ba5abf5fb904cfed9a601e4489ef Merge branch 'master' of ssh://github.com/fezzee/FezzeeIOS
a8d025d86819c152c577340eb2d4ee8924890ccc v1.1.59
:
```

If I then get the commits between (and including) the tags , the results don't match:

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline --decorate  1.1.64^..1.1.65
8f326b8ac5dc4ae5d1e9097d91ef460a39e9bda2 (HEAD, tag: 1.1.65, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) following fixes done
aef34c6dec4890384ca5fd318988d14a5b7af327 chat Input Field to have padding from the left....
adbad9b9aa74bb9664521780adb50272181eca23 changed setting name from LogEntries to Live Log
58476d5f72abe603c2b0ec3bf54a40a82fbafb90 Merge branch 'master' of ssh://github.com/fezzee/FezzeeIOS
77f3d951a3ad7099667b98dd1622279da5fc8c3d prevent legacy setting lock in, remove 2 observers when view is unloaded, possible better test in 
ed48862949890604b044e4cf20bc6bcff4a8674a Merge branch 'master' of ssh://github.com/fezzee/FezzeeIOS
07bf561ef4eb55fddd732d796a0014aa8d992df8 (tag: 1.1.64) Fixed Issues:
25cb2fcf57915b417d9f8404f1eca9c44704245d Merge branch 'master' of ssh://github.com/fezzee/FezzeeIOS
5bd194a9ade3cfc172e218c43b398ebe9bce7126 v1.1.62
ac8e14dc810c85ddab09e25a3efdc3c7b1cc8ff5 fixed merge conflict
418ff451d236ba5abf5fb904cfed9a601e4489ef Merge branch 'master' of ssh://github.com/fezzee/FezzeeIOS
a8d025d86819c152c577340eb2d4ee8924890ccc v1.1.59
```

I was expecting:

```
8f326b8ac5dc4ae5d1e9097d91ef460a39e9bda2 (HEAD, tag: 1.1.65, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) following fixes done
aef34c6dec4890384ca5fd318988d14a5b7af327 chat Input Field to have padding from the left....
adbad9b9aa74bb9664521780adb50272181eca23 changed setting name from LogEntries to Live Log
58476d5f72abe603c2b0ec3bf54a40a82fbafb90 Merge branch 'master' of ssh://github.com/fezzee/FezzeeIOS
77f3d951a3ad7099667b98dd1622279da5fc8c3d prevent legacy setting lock in, remove 2 observers when view is unloaded, possible better test in 
ed48862949890604b044e4cf20bc6bcff4a8674a Merge branch 'master' of ssh://github.com/fezzee/FezzeeIOS
07bf561ef4eb55fddd732d796a0014aa8d992df8 (tag: 1.1.64) Fixed Issues:
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Can anyone suggest a better way of creating a simple change log, than using the commandline below?

git log --pretty=oneline --decorate  1.1.64^..1.1.65

Comment: since you have several merges in your history, please post graph history excerpts instead (add the `--graph` option to your `log` calls)

Comment: thank you, once I did this I could easily see the issue

Comment: it would be nice of you to update your question with the graph logs, if possible, and post an answer yourself, for the benefit if other users :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from Nevik Rehnel hinted at what I needed to do to create relevant release notes from my git comments; ignore the comments relating to merges.

I use:

`git log --no-merges --decorate x.x.xx^..x.x.xx`

then I copy everything the last comment, which was the previous tag. I only include it to be sure I have all comments included.

I hope this is useful to others. I've been using this for a few months now.